# See AST of an mli file

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I want to be able to see what the AST of a certain module would be so I can write a proper filter against it.

As I right now don't really see how I can 'log' in a filter, for example I try to match and when the match fails I log, I use the Camlp4AstLifter function to translate the module into a tree, which is then printed out on the console, and like that I try to create my match patterns, like so:

```
camlp4o -filter Camlp4AstLifter -printer o name_of_file.ml
```

This falls a bit short right now when I would like to take an mli file and use a camlp4 filter to create a default implementation of this mli file.

I cannot use Camlp4AstLifter to see the tree, becuase this command doesn't seem to work with mli's (it shows me the mli again as output) and therefore I'm a bit blind while trying to match.

Anybody got an idea? Or maybe a hint on how to improve my filtering/matching approach (I don't get the feeling I'm doing it right yet, very tedious).

Kasper

Answer (score 0):

Put `module type S = <contents of mli file>` into ml file and apply the lifter?

Comment: Yes, well I tried that first, but it doesn't seem to give the same tree as an mli file, or my matching is off of course, and the objective is to have both in the end, so a module with a type inside the ml file and a module with a type in the mli file. Therefore, I need to try to get the tree of the mli file as well. Which, like I said, seems to be a bit off when compared to a type declared internally in a module.

Answer (score 0):

The ocaml compilers have some undocumented switches, that are nevertheless shown when doing `ocamlc -h` (probably thanks to the module Arg), ocamlopt has even more:

```
-dsource  (undocumented)
-dparsetree  (undocumented)
-dtypedtree  (undocumented)
-drawlambda  (undocumented)
-dlambda  (undocumented)
-dclambda  (undocumented)
...
```

I found out that -dsource gives a prettyprinting of the source. Your desired option should be there, too.